# C# PadRight Backslash or Frontslash

Tags: c#

Trying to get a file path from user via cmd input. Want to make sure that there is a "/" or "\" at the end of the file path. Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please specify file location:");
string fileLocation = @Console.ReadLine(); 
fileLocation = fileLocation.PadRight(1, '/');
```

However when testing it doesn't seem to add the character. What is wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Because that's not what PadRight does. Did you check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Ken yes I did. Maybe I did not understand it. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @Poplop `PadRight` will pad your string with the given character until it's the length you specify.  So when you pass 1 it will only pad if the string is empty.  But really why do you need to ensure that there is a path separator at the end?  If it's because you do something like `var filePath = fileLocation + fileName;` then I suggest you look into using `Path.Combine` which will handle the separators for you.  Or in the case of Urls you can use the `Uri` class which has a constructor that takes a base and relative path.

Comment: @juharr thanks for the explanation. I will look into Path.Combine.

Comment: I see @juharr beat me to it. :-) *Returns a new string that left-aligns the characters in this string by padding them on the right with a specified Unicode character, for a specified total length.* The significant part is *for a specified total length*, which you've specified as 1. Thus, the function does nothing to filename, because it's already more than 1 in length.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for further clarification :)

Comment: @juharr thanks for Path.Combine. Really useful, does exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you actually want to use `PadRight`

> Returns a new string of a specified length in which the end of the current string is padded with spaces or with a specified Unicode character.

What about just checking for it and appending it to the end of the string if it doesnt exist instead:

```
if(!fileLocation.EndsWith("/")) 
{
    fileLocation += "/";
}
```